# How to better optimize SQL queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote the request, but I'm afraid it can be very unoptimized and I will have a problem.

Task: **Find users who have no debts and their last payment was older than 2 years. Unnecessary users who did not have any order**

We have two tables:

```
 User tbl (Id (int), LastName (string))
```

```
 Order tbl (Id (int), UserId (int), IsPaid (bool), DatePaid (Date, not null))
```

I wrote a Sql request, but I'm afraid I'm down with 20k of users and lots of orders

I have found all those who have no debts and the last payment is for a period of two years.
Now I want to remove them from the general list and so users who need me remain.
It seems bad idea

```
SELECT u."Id"
FROM "User" AS u
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT *
    FROM "Order"
    WHERE "UserId" IN
       (SELECT "Id"
        FROM "User"
        WHERE "Id" NOT IN
           (SELECT DISTINCT "UserId"
            FROM "Order"
            WHERE "IsPaid" IS FALSE )
       )
    AND "DatePaid" > '2016-10-10'
   ) AS p
   ON p."UserId" = u."Id";
```

Comment: You are nearly there I guess. Please tag your Database and some sample data. we will definitely help improve your answer. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Why do you have `IsConfirmedOnAccountingSystem` in the nested select instead of having it in you external query? Maybe I'm missing something but it feels like you're overcomplicating this a bit.

Comment: Can you correct your schema summary? I'd guess IsConfirmedOnAccountingSystem == IsPaid, and DateConfirmed == DatePaid?

Comment: Sorry it must be "IsPaid" not "IsConfirmedOnAccountingSystem"

Comment: Please explain how you know if someone has no debts.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: IsPaid means that the user has paid the order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want something like this:

```
select o.userid
from orders o
group by o.userid
having sum(case when o.isPaid then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) and -- all are paid
       max(o.paymentdate) < current_date - interval '2 year';
```

Note that date functions are notoriously database specific.  The above uses ANSI/ISO standard syntax.

If you want full information about the users, then you can use a different structure:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.userid = u.id and not u.ispaid
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.userid = u.id and
                        u.paymentdate > current_date - interval '2 year'
                 );
```

Comment: It seems that I have forgotten the opportunity to say that unnecessary users who did not have any order. But looks like nice this code :)

Comment: @TomTom . . . The first query only returns users who have orders.  The second returns those plus users with no orders at all.